# ruby's Mail gem: how to see if attachment is inline

Tags: ruby, email-attachments, mail-gem

Say, i have a raw mail message in a file and i read it like

```
m = Mail.read '/path/to/file'
```

it has attachments, one of which is an inline pic.

```
pic = m.attachments[0]
 => #<Mail::Part:70130030888740, Multipart: false, Headers: <Content-Type: image/png; name="image001.png">, <Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64>, <Content-ID: <image001.png@01D21F1C.E063ADE0>>>
```

others are just some files.

**What i need** is to have a way of knowing whether the attachment is inline or not. There is an `inline?` method, and for non-inline attachments it works like a charm

```
pdf = m.attachments[1]
 => #<Mail::Part:70130031002140, Multipart: false, Headers: <Content-Type: application/pdf; name="blah blah blah blah
pdf.inline?
=> false
```

But let's return to our `pic` here:

```
pic.inline?
=> nil
```

Which is just not right. I also tried

```
pdf['Content-Disposition']
=> #<Mail::Field 0x7f90d729b598 @charset="UTF-8" @name="Content-Disposition" @raw_value="Content-Disposition: attachment;\r\n\tfilename
```

and

```
pic['Content-Disposition']
=> nil
```

which is not too good either.

**Is there any way to have a true/false value here?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, the pic doesn't have a `Content-Disposition` header defined. What to make of this differs a bit between standards (some default to `attachment`, some to `inline`). To quote [RFC 2183](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2183#section-2):

> Content-Disposition is an optional header field. In its absence, the
> MUA may use whatever presentation method it deems suitable.

The [mail gem](https://github.com/mikel/mail/blob/94a1998e9855728f079a032574001b0349ef743d/lib/mail/part.rb#L37-L39) seems to default to `attachment` since it only checks if the Content-Disposition was explicitly set to `inline`.

If you want to default to `inline` instead, you can check if the result of the `inline?` method returns anything else but `false`.

```
pic_is_inline = (pic.inline? != false) # pic.inline? returns nil
# => true

pdf_is_inline = (pdf.inline? != false) # pdf.inline? returns false
# => false
```

In the end, it's up to little defined semantics and you will have to be rather careful since these things tend to be interpreted differently by different people. When you accept mail from unknown sources, you could e.g. check if an attachment without an explicit `Content-Disposition` is referenced in the mail body somehow.